# (C#) Can I access a struct's members by name or index?

Tags: c#, struct

Is it possible to access a struct's public members by their names / indices?

For example, if I have:

```
struct Person
{
  int id;
  string surname;
}

Person person;
```

Is it possible to get `person.id` with just the string "id" or the integer index 0?
Or to get `person.surname` with the string "surname" or the integer index 1?

Comment: You can access a member by name using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to get member by name (in this case field):

```
var p = new Person();
var fieldInfo = p.GetType().GetField("id", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo.GetValue(p)); // prints 0
```